# Error code 1146 Table '<table_name>' doesn't exist MySql error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this query which worked 3-4 times but all of a sudden its execution is throwing errors -

```
Error Code: 1146
Table 'bugs.PROFILES' doesn't exist
```

What could have gone wrong all of a sudded?

I also did `RESET QUERY CACHE` but no luck.

Below is the query -

```
SELECT b.bug_id                           AS Bug_Id, 
       b.bug_status                       AS STATUS, 
       b.resolution                       AS Resolution, 
       q.realname                         AS Reporter, 
       p.realname                         AS Assigned_To, 
       b.short_desc                       AS Summary, 
       DATE_FORMAT(b.deadline, '%m/%d/%Y')AS Deadline 
FROM   bugs b 
       INNER JOIN PROFILES p 
               ON b.assigned_to = p.userid 
       INNER JOIN PROFILES q 
               ON b.reporter = q.userid 
WHERE  ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST', 'REOPENED' ) 
         AND short_desc NOT LIKE '%Program:%' 
         AND deadline BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
       ) 
        OR ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
             AND short_desc NOT LIKE '%Program:%' 
             AND deadline BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND 
                                  CURDATE() ) 
ORDER  BY bug_status ASC
```

Any suggestions pls?

The table bugs.profiles does exist.

[image: bugs.profiles]

[image: b.reporter column]

Comment: Does the table exist? `SHOW TABLES` should tell you.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  Yes it does, have added the screenshot in desc.

Comment: "The table bugs.profiles does exist."

No, it doesn't. Your screenshot shows no rows in the query result.

Comment: This is probably one of those completely bogus error messages produced by mysql due to some syntax error somewhere (anywhere) in your query.  Try to simplify your query to find out which part contains the syntax error. Your first suspect should be the most recent modification that you made to the query.

Comment: If you just `SHOW TABLES` rather than `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'bugs.PROFILES'`, you will understand that it doesn't exist, and the pseudo column name returned in your other attempt gives you a misleading result.

Comment: @MikeNakis No, the problem is that `bugs.PROFILES` is a non-existent profile. It's a very clear error.

Comment: But the same query was working fine and all of a sudden this error started. Also, I am trying to minimize the query by removing some clauses but no luck.

Comment: @MikeNakis So on removing the second inner join it worked.. But why would that be?

Comment: I do not know, but perhaps because there is no such thing as b.reporter.  Reporter seems to exist only as an alias of q.realname.

Comment: If that is the case, then please let me know, and I will turn my comment into an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: @MikeNakis Pls find the screenshot for b.reporter in desc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69905/discussion-between-softwaretestingenthusiast-and-mike-nakis).

Answer (score 2):

It's tell you that `bugs.PROFILES` table doesn't exist. Check it manually in `bugs` database, `PROFILES` table. Or by using `SHOW TABLES`

There are possibility your tables missing when you are moving database to new location or updating your mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the answer

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'bugs.PROFILES'
```